# How to disable the enter key from going second line when onpress?

Tags: enter

I want the enter key to save the data to database, but whenever I press it will break and create second line, I just want it stay at one line

```
<div id="editable" contentEditable="true">Press enter now</div>
```

Comment: What language? What database? Please give us more to work with.

Comment: check the keycode of the key that has been pressed, if it is 13 then the enter key has been pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a jquery solution.

```
$('input').on('keypress', function(e){
if(e.keyCode == 13){
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

});