# catch 'enter' press from contenteditable <li> element while typing

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML code:

```
<li class="option-item new" contenteditable="true">simple element2</li>
```

When ENTER key is clicked while editing this element, I want to exit editing mode (set contentEditable to false) instead of typing in line break. So I've attached the following event listner:

```
$("#ctx-options").on('keypress', '.option-item.new', catch_enter);
```

The problem is that the event is not triggered for ENTER key, although it is triggered for all other keys. I don't understand why. The same approach that I'm using was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954446/how-to-disable-the-enter-key-from-going-second-line-when-onpress), but it doens't work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287630/how-to-deactive-enter-event-only-enter-no-shiftenter-in-contenteditable/18287959) a similar question today. You'll have to use the `keydown` event. `keypress` will only work for a limited subset of keys (the return key seems to work for me, but the arrow keys do not work; as far as I know, keypress only works reliably for alphanumeric characters).

Answer (score 8):

You need to bind to `keydown`, since when `keypress` has triggered, the event has already occured:

```
$("#ctx-options").on('keydown', '.option-item.new', function(e) {  
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Please see the [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zVu8R/)

Comment: `keypress` and `keydown` both works. i updated your fiddle with keypress it still works, `keypress` i don't believe catch `ctrl` keys `mouse clicks` etc

Comment: Not a problem. Thought I'd save your from phantom downvoters.

Answer (score 0):

On W3Schools they have this solution using only javascript. They use a input but it works with a contenteditable html element.

https://www.w3schools.com/HOWTO/howto_js_trigger_button_enter.asp

```
// Get the input field
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");

// Execute a function when the user presses a key on the keyboard
input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  // If the user presses the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    // Cancel the default action, if needed
    event.preventDefault();
    // Trigger the button element with a click
    document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
  }
});
```

If you need the shift key to be captured to allow the enter to typed then just change the if line to this:

```
if (event.key === "Enter" && !event.shiftKey ) {
```